# substitution rules for Penrose tiles

Tags: graphics

[This page on W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=penrose+tiles) shows a nice substitution rule to draw kites and darts.

I'd like to implement the rule in *Mathematica*, so I've drawn the original kite and its replacement (separately).  I've also drawn the original dart and its replacement.  This seems like a job for `Replace[]`, but I'm not sure how.  I know there are similar animations on Demonstrations, but I'd like to create my own (with help!).

In my mind, this would be cool as a `Manipulate[]` environment, where the slider controls the number of times the replacement has occurred.  Maybe even a rotation slider, too, so the kites and darts tile space in a particular direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your progress so far.

Comment: Please see Mathematica in Action by Stan Wagon. Chapter 9 of the second edition discusses Penrose tiles. It is available via Google Books. Try Googling: "TriangleDissection" "KitesAndDarts".

Comment: You will want to see [the third edition of Wagon's book as well](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-75477-2_11).

Comment: @J.M Interesting link - 8 pages for `$30`, or the whole book (578 pages) for `$70` on Amazon... ‽

Comment: @cormullion, yes, the pricing is something to be puzzled about. In my case, I am thankful for the library who allows me access to these things and worries about the prices so I don't have to. :)

Answer (score 12):

Your question is too general for this site, but since I already have the code, let me give you a start. You have two replacement rules for the two different shapes `t1` and `t2` (note that I use triangles)

```
subdivide = {
   t1[{a_, b_, c_}] :> 
    With[{p1 = a + (b - a)/GoldenRatio, 
      p2 = c + (a - c)/GoldenRatio},
     {t2[{p2, p1, a}], t1[{c, p1, b}], t1[{c, p1, p2}]}], 
   t2[{a_, b_, c_}] :> With[{p = c + (b - c)/GoldenRatio},
     {t1[{c, a, p}], t2[{p, a, b}]}
     ]
   };
```

When you now start with an `initial` set of shapes you can use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) and `Nest` to apply the rules several times.

```
penrose = 
  With[{initial = t1[{0.0, Exp[-I*Pi/10.0], Exp[I*Pi/10.0]}]}, 
   Nest[# /. subdivide &, initial, 3]];
```

In a last step you need to convert the data types `t1` and `t2` into shapes you can really draw. For this, just use another rule which transforms them into e.g. `Polygone`'s.

```
draw = {t1[arg_] :> {GrayLevel[.95], 
     Polygon[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ arg]}, 
   t2[arg_] :> {GrayLevel[.85], Polygon[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ arg]}};
```

The rest is easy, apply the draw rule and put it into a `Graphics`

```
Graphics[penrose /. draw]
```

When you use more iterations (e.g. 6) you get what you expect

[image]

For further information, you can read along [this question on Meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/341/187).

To make this all dynamic, you just need to put `Manipulate` around it and make some variable dynamic. E.g. To change the initial points, you could use `Locator`'s

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  With[{initial = t1[{Complex @@ p1, Complex @@ p2, Complex @@ p3}],
    draw = {t1[arg_] :> {GrayLevel[.95], EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], 
        Polygon[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ arg]}, 
      t2[arg_] :> {GrayLevel[.85], EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], 
        Polygon[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ arg]}}}, 
   Nest[# /. subdivide &, initial, 6] /. draw]
  , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{p1, {-1, 0}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {1, 0.5}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {1, -0.5}}, Locator}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great.  Thanks so much.  I didn't realize all that information was on Meta, but that looks helpful as well.  

Out of curiosity, what makes this question too general for the site?  I'm fairly new to Mathematica and a little frustrated by what I perceive to be a steep learning curve.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user6353 The question is IMO too general because you haven't asked a specific question like *I want to create a Penrose pattern, here is what I have so far but it doesn't work. I expect this but instead I get that...* Furthermore, it is always good to search the site before asking, which wouldn't have worked out since the Penrose post was on Meta. Have you read the [FAQ] and [this answer on Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/734/187)?

Comment: Hi.  Ok, good to know.  In my mind, I should be able to do something like this: Replace[kite, kite->kiteSubstitution, 5], though that usage of Replace only works one level deep.  I had poked around the FAQ but not seen the details about Penrose tiles on Meta, so I'll keep at it.  Thanks again.